# Is it possible to add leading zeros to the day and month in rails' date_select and datetime_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, helper

I'm trying to add leading zeros to the days and months in a date_select, and for all I can see in the docs you can only specify `:use_month_numbers` and `:use_short_month` 
but not `:leading_zeros => true`.

Looking at the rails code, I found that the following code in date_helper.rb:

File: [actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb)

```
def select_day
  if @options[:use_hidden] || @options[:discard_day]
    build_hidden(:day, day)
  else
    build_options_and_select(:day, day, :start => 1, :end => 31, :leading_zeros => false)
  end
end
```

And in line 856 under DateTimeSelector, there's a line that goes:

```
leading_zeros = options.delete(:leading_zeros)
```

So I get the impression that even if you managed to override the first method, and called `DateTimeSelector` with `leading_zeros => true`, that it would just end your party there, so it's not possible to do this this way.

Now, my ruby-fu / rails-fu is not that legendary so I was wondering – could I override the class in my rails app reimplementing only the method(s) I want in order to support leading_zeros, or what would be the best way way to get this to work?

EDIT: In case someone's asking *why does he even need leading zeroes?*, well, it's not a deal breaker, and it's not *necessary*, but I would like to be able to do this… just for consistency across the app. The dates are displayed with a dd/mm/yy format across app and in reports, but when creating the records the user finds a different format. It's not so important, just a design choice.

Comment: Since this is only for presentation purposes, I'm currently using Javascript to zero-pad the `<option>` text content, as it makes no difference that the value has a leading zero or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Anyway*… I finally solved this by overloading the method in the rails app (as a test, not using it in production). I guess I can close this as "rails does not support leading zeros in dates".

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, just use format like this: "%-d %-m"